# What is the type of the Value that can be inputed in a JSON Array / Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Knowing that, in JSON format, the Object and the Array structures can contain respectively pairs of name/value and ordered collection of values and that the values can be object/array/string/number/true/false/null ; is it correct to say that in an array (or in an object) the type of value can vary ?

Meaning by that that i can have for example this array :

[String,Number,Array,Array,Object] or it must be this way [String,String,...] or [Array,Array,...] (same type of value all over the array)

Same question for the object structure. (concerning the value part of the pair keyname/value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can associate any type of value with any property of another object, and you can add any type of value into an array.

For example, this is perfectly valid JSON:

```
{
 "key1": 1,
 "key2": "Two",
 "key3": ["Three", 4, {"five": "six"}, ["seven"]]
}
```

... which can be used to define a value, as you see here:

[image]

Comment: Can I have then var data = { "array" : "[ "1", { }, "abc"]" } ?

Comment: You can stack anything in the JSON as it is a String, but good luck with parsing that thingy ;)

Comment: @MaxZoom: Yeah, if you're ever planning to deserialize something from your JSON string, you definitely want a more static structure. But JavaScript is a scripting language. You can do just about anything you want.

Comment: I know that in JavaScript an Array is also an Object- this is why it worked. But it will create problems when you would like to apply any algorithm to it like sorting, concatenating, etc. That is why it should contain a single type.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the type of elements in an array can vary. For example

```
var a = ["hello", 12345, {key : "value"}, true];
```

This is valid javascript. However it is bad practice to have more than one type in an array as you have to know the order of the expected element to access them. e.g. you have to know that the first element is a string.

It would be better to represent the above array as an object with named properties:

```
   var o = {
      aString : "hello",
      aNumber : 12345, 
      aSubobject : {
         key : "value"
      },
      aBool : true
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array by definition should contain only the elements of the same type.
The object however may contain different element types. This is the basic assumption in JSON.

Comment: Arrays in javascript do not have to contain objects of the same type although it is good practice to ensure that they do.

Answer (score 0):

The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, and String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.